# Node-Red app asks "Welcome to your new Node-RED instance" again

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

IBM Cloud Node-Red app asks "Welcome to your new Node-RED instance" again even after configuring the "Secure your Node-RED editor". 
Where is the configuration "Secure your Node-RED editor" stored?

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

Comment: Have you renamed the IBM Cloud application or changed the Cloudant DB instance?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the configuration "Secure your Node-RED editor" stored?

This information is stored in the ***settings*** json file which in case of IBM Cloud can be found in the **cloudant No SQL DB** that is linked to your Node-RED application.

Here below an example extract of this json file.  The actual credentials to secure your Node-RED editor are encoded under **"adminAuth"** element.

```html
{
  "_id": "jvda-sensor/settings",
  "_rev": "8-6cd81cf966e4faaf92b65269186bab98",
  "settings": {
    "bluemixConfig": {
      "adminAuth": {
        "username": "jvda",
        "password": "$2a$0.......aSr5/3y",
        "allowAnonymous": false
      }
    },
    "nodes": {
      "node-red": {
        "name": "node-red",
        "version": "0.19.3",
        "local": false,
        "nodes": {
          "sentiment": {
            "name": "sentiment",
```